# Detect audio and video input devices and get its status (C# Windows Service)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need to get audio and video input devices in the system and get its status.

I was doing it like this using `DirectShow`

```
public class DeviceMonitoringService
{
    public static DsDevice[] DetectMicrophone()
    {
        var audioDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.AudioInputDevice);
        return audioDevices;
    }

    public static DsDevice[] DetectCamera()
    {
        var videoDevices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        return videoDevices;
    }
}
```

But this approach doesn't return the status of the device.

How I can get the status?

Answer (score 0):

So for audio input I can use [NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio) nuget

And detect all inputs like this

```
public static List<InputDevice> GetAudioInputDevices()
    {
        var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        var devicesAudio = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Capture, DeviceState.All);

        return devicesAudio.Select(device => new InputDevice()
            {DeviceId = device.ID, Name = device.DeviceFriendlyName, Status = device.State.ToString()}).ToList();
    }
```